# using lxml with beautiful soup

Tags: html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm having trouble making lxml work with beautiful soup. Running on osx 10.8.4. To install lxml, i did port install py25-lxml and it installed fine. Now I'm getting this error when I try to use lxml with Beautiful Soup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "********.py", line 13, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'lxml')
  File "/Users/********/********/bs4/__init__.py", line 155, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.
Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Not sure if this is part of the problem, but I'm unable to import lxml.etree

Has anyone else gotten lxml to work with beautiful soup on osx?

Also, maybe I could just try to use a different html parser. Does anyone have suggestions for other parsers?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I had to manually download `lxml` on my mac for it to work. Try this

Answer (score 0):

From the lxml website:

If this fails attempt to build it yourself
http://lxml.de/build.html#building-lxml-on-macos-x

This may not work so don't rely on it

Otherwise there are other parsers such as lxml.html (should work with lxml) and a few others that I'm not sure of.